# Отключение/Включение СОМ-порта

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows

Ребят, подскажите, как можно отключить, а потом включить СОМ-порт программно?

Бывает, что порты отваливаются, и нужно их перезапустить через диспетчер устройств. Хотелось бы реализовать это программно.

**Операционная система**: Windows 10

Comment: Вот этот ответ поможет: [Win32 API function to programmatically enable/disable device](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1610140/5275890)

Comment: @DenisBubnov, отличный ответ, не могли бы вы его перевести и разместить тут в качестве ответа(со ссылкой на оригинал)?

Comment: @vp_arth, могу, немного позже опубликую :)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programmatically-enable-disable-device

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете включить/отключить устройства от Win32 (и, следовательно, из C# с помощью P/Invoke) с использованием SetupDi API, но не все устройства таким образом можно отключить.

Проблему Вы будете получать, например, при попытке отключения тачпада от Win32 (или WMI или любой другой API, который вызывает из в `SetupDi*`- семейства функций). Причина в том, что драйвер мыши по умолчанию, которые в большинстве ноутбуков с сенсорной панелью (*"PS/2-совместимая мышь"*), не поддерживает отключение с помощью SetupDi API. Возможно это может быть потому, что старые мыши, использующие `PS/2` - разъем не могут быть отсоединены *на горячую* без перезагрузки оборудования.

Для того, чтобы убедиться в том, что Вы можете отключить устройство, перейдите в <kbd>Диспетчер устройств</kbd> и щелкните правой кнопкой мыши на устройстве мыши в списке устройств. Если там есть опция <kbd>Отключить</kbd> и она активна, то Вы можете использовать `SetupDi`, чтобы отключить это устройство. Если нет опции отключения - увы, не повезло, этого сделать не получится.

Если Вы видите опцию <kbd>Отключить</kbd>, то приведенный код ниже должен позволить Вам отключить и повторно включить устройство.

Код для вызова вспомогательной библиотеки:

```
public static void EnableMouse(bool enable)
{
    // every type of device has a hard-coded GUID, this is the one for mice
    Guid mouseGuid = new Guid("{4d36e96f-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}");

    // get this from the properties dialog box of this device in Device Manager
    string instancePath = @"ACPI\PNP0F03\4&3688D3F&0";

    DeviceHelper.SetDeviceEnabled(mouseGuid, instancePath, enable);
}
```

Вот сама вспомогательная библиотека, взято [отсюда](https://jo0ls-dotnet-stuff.blogspot.ru/2009/01/enabledisable-device-programmatically.html):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DisableDevice;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Security;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Management;

namespace DisableDevice
{

    [Flags()]
    internal enum SetupDiGetClassDevsFlags
    {
        Default = 1,
        Present = 2,
        AllClasses = 4,
        Profile = 8,
        DeviceInterface = (int)0x10
    }

    internal enum DiFunction
    {
        SelectDevice = 1,
        InstallDevice = 2,
        AssignResources = 3,
        Properties = 4,
        Remove = 5,
        FirstTimeSetup = 6,
        FoundDevice = 7,
        SelectClassDrivers = 8,
        ValidateClassDrivers = 9,
        InstallClassDrivers = (int)0xa,
        CalcDiskSpace = (int)0xb,
        DestroyPrivateData = (int)0xc,
        ValidateDriver = (int)0xd,
        Detect = (int)0xf,
        InstallWizard = (int)0x10,
        DestroyWizardData = (int)0x11,
        PropertyChange = (int)0x12,
        EnableClass = (int)0x13,
        DetectVerify = (int)0x14,
        InstallDeviceFiles = (int)0x15,
        UnRemove = (int)0x16,
        SelectBestCompatDrv = (int)0x17,
        AllowInstall = (int)0x18,
        RegisterDevice = (int)0x19,
        NewDeviceWizardPreSelect = (int)0x1a,
        NewDeviceWizardSelect = (int)0x1b,
        NewDeviceWizardPreAnalyze = (int)0x1c,
        NewDeviceWizardPostAnalyze = (int)0x1d,
        NewDeviceWizardFinishInstall = (int)0x1e,
        Unused1 = (int)0x1f,
        InstallInterfaces = (int)0x20,
        DetectCancel = (int)0x21,
        RegisterCoInstallers = (int)0x22,
        AddPropertyPageAdvanced = (int)0x23,
        AddPropertyPageBasic = (int)0x24,
        Reserved1 = (int)0x25,
        Troubleshooter = (int)0x26,
        PowerMessageWake = (int)0x27,
        AddRemotePropertyPageAdvanced = (int)0x28,
        UpdateDriverUI = (int)0x29,
        Reserved2 = (int)0x30
    }

    internal enum StateChangeAction
    {
        Enable = 1,
        Disable = 2,
        PropChange = 3,
        Start = 4,
        Stop = 5
    }

    [Flags()]
    internal enum Scopes
    {
        Global = 1,
        ConfigSpecific = 2,
        ConfigGeneral = 4
    }

    internal enum SetupApiError
    {
        NoAssociatedClass = unchecked((int)0xe0000200),
        ClassMismatch = unchecked((int)0xe0000201),
        DuplicateFound = unchecked((int)0xe0000202),
        NoDriverSelected = unchecked((int)0xe0000203),
        KeyDoesNotExist = unchecked((int)0xe0000204),
        InvalidDevinstName = unchecked((int)0xe0000205),
        InvalidClass = unchecked((int)0xe0000206),
        DevinstAlreadyExists = unchecked((int)0xe0000207),
        DevinfoNotRegistered = unchecked((int)0xe0000208),
        InvalidRegProperty = unchecked((int)0xe0000209),
        NoInf = unchecked((int)0xe000020a),
        NoSuchHDevinst = unchecked((int)0xe000020b),
        CantLoadClassIcon = unchecked((int)0xe000020c),
        InvalidClassInstaller = unchecked((int)0xe000020d),
        DiDoDefault = unchecked((int)0xe000020e),
        DiNoFileCopy = unchecked((int)0xe000020f),
        InvalidHwProfile = unchecked((int)0xe0000210),
        NoDeviceSelected = unchecked((int)0xe0000211),
        DevinfolistLocked = unchecked((int)0xe0000212),
        DevinfodataLocked = unchecked((int)0xe0000213),
        DiBadPath = unchecked((int)0xe0000214),
        NoClassInstallParams = unchecked((int)0xe0000215),
        FileQueueLocked = unchecked((int)0xe0000216),
        BadServiceInstallSect = unchecked((int)0xe0000217),
        NoClassDriverList = unchecked((int)0xe0000218),
        NoAssociatedService = unchecked((int)0xe0000219),
        NoDefaultDeviceInterface = unchecked((int)0xe000021a),
        DeviceInterfaceActive = unchecked((int)0xe000021b),
        DeviceInterfaceRemoved = unchecked((int)0xe000021c),
        BadInterfaceInstallSect = unchecked((int)0xe000021d),
        NoSuchInterfaceClass = unchecked((int)0xe000021e),
        InvalidReferenceString = unchecked((int)0xe000021f),
        InvalidMachineName = unchecked((int)0xe0000220),
        RemoteCommFailure = unchecked((int)0xe0000221),
        MachineUnavailable = unchecked((int)0xe0000222),
        NoConfigMgrServices = unchecked((int)0xe0000223),
        InvalidPropPageProvider = unchecked((int)0xe0000224),
        NoSuchDeviceInterface = unchecked((int)0xe0000225),
        DiPostProcessingRequired = unchecked((int)0xe0000226),
        InvalidCOInstaller = unchecked((int)0xe0000227),
        NoCompatDrivers = unchecked((int)0xe0000228),
        NoDeviceIcon = unchecked((int)0xe0000229),
        InvalidInfLogConfig = unchecked((int)0xe000022a),
        DiDontInstall = unchecked((int)0xe000022b),
        InvalidFilterDriver = unchecked((int)0xe000022c),
        NonWindowsNTDriver = unchecked((int)0xe000022d),
        NonWindowsDriver = unchecked((int)0xe000022e),
        NoCatalogForOemInf = unchecked((int)0xe000022f),
        DevInstallQueueNonNative = unchecked((int)0xe0000230),
        NotDisableable = unchecked((int)0xe0000231),
        CantRemoveDevinst = unchecked((int)0xe0000232),
        InvalidTarget = unchecked((int)0xe0000233),
        DriverNonNative = unchecked((int)0xe0000234),
        InWow64 = unchecked((int)0xe0000235),
        SetSystemRestorePoint = unchecked((int)0xe0000236),
        IncorrectlyCopiedInf = unchecked((int)0xe0000237),
        SceDisabled = unchecked((int)0xe0000238),
        UnknownException = unchecked((int)0xe0000239),
        PnpRegistryError = unchecked((int)0xe000023a),
        RemoteRequestUnsupported = unchecked((int)0xe000023b),
        NotAnInstalledOemInf = unchecked((int)0xe000023c),
        InfInUseByDevices = unchecked((int)0xe000023d),
        DiFunctionObsolete = unchecked((int)0xe000023e),
        NoAuthenticodeCatalog = unchecked((int)0xe000023f),
        AuthenticodeDisallowed = unchecked((int)0xe0000240),
        AuthenticodeTrustedPublisher = unchecked((int)0xe0000241),
        AuthenticodeTrustNotEstablished = unchecked((int)0xe0000242),
        AuthenticodePublisherNotTrusted = unchecked((int)0xe0000243),
        SignatureOSAttributeMismatch = unchecked((int)0xe0000244),
        OnlyValidateViaAuthenticode = unchecked((int)0xe0000245)
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct DeviceInfoData
    {
        public int Size;
        public Guid ClassGuid;
        public int DevInst;
        public IntPtr Reserved;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct PropertyChangeParameters
    {
        public int Size;
        // part of header. It's flattened out into 1 structure.
        public DiFunction DiFunction;
        public StateChangeAction StateChange;
        public Scopes Scope;
        public int HwProfile;
    }

    internal class NativeMethods
    {

        private const string setupapi = "setupapi.dll";

        private NativeMethods()
        {
        }

        [DllImport(setupapi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DiFunction installFunction, SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle deviceInfoSet, [In()]
ref DeviceInfoData deviceInfoData);

        [DllImport(setupapi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle deviceInfoSet, int memberIndex, ref DeviceInfoData deviceInfoData);

        [DllImport(setupapi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle SetupDiGetClassDevs([In()]
ref Guid classGuid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
string enumerator, IntPtr hwndParent, SetupDiGetClassDevsFlags flags);

        /*
        [DllImport(setupapi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle deviceInfoSet, [In()]
ref DeviceInfoData did, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
StringBuilder deviceInstanceId, int deviceInstanceIdSize, [Out()]
ref int requiredSize);
        */
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(
           IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
           ref DeviceInfoData did,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] StringBuilder DeviceInstanceId,
           int DeviceInstanceIdSize,
           out int RequiredSize
        );

        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
        [DllImport(setupapi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(IntPtr deviceInfoSet);

        [DllImport(setupapi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle deviceInfoSet, [In()]
ref DeviceInfoData deviceInfoData, [In()]
ref PropertyChangeParameters classInstallParams, int classInstallParamsSize);

    }

    internal class SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {

        public SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle()
            : base(true)
        {
        }

        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return NativeMethods.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(this.handle);
        }

    }

    public sealed class DeviceHelper
    {

        private DeviceHelper()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enable or disable a device.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="classGuid">The class guid of the device. Available in the device manager.</param>
        /// <param name="instanceId">The device instance id of the device. Available in the device manager.</param>
        /// <param name="enable">True to enable, False to disable.</param>
        /// <remarks>Will throw an exception if the device is not Disableable.</remarks>
        public static void SetDeviceEnabled(Guid classGuid, string instanceId, bool enable)
        {
            SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle diSetHandle = null;
            try
            {
                // Get the handle to a device information set for all devices matching classGuid that are present on the 
                // system.
                diSetHandle = NativeMethods.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref classGuid, null, IntPtr.Zero, SetupDiGetClassDevsFlags.Present);
                // Get the device information data for each matching device.
                DeviceInfoData[] diData = GetDeviceInfoData(diSetHandle);
                // Find the index of our instance. i.e. the touchpad mouse - I have 3 mice attached...
                int index = GetIndexOfInstance(diSetHandle, diData, instanceId);
                // Disable...
                EnableDevice(diSetHandle, diData[index], enable);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (diSetHandle != null)
                {
                    if (diSetHandle.IsClosed == false)
                    {
                        diSetHandle.Close();
                    }
                    diSetHandle.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        private static DeviceInfoData[] GetDeviceInfoData(SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle handle)
        {
            List<DeviceInfoData> data = new List<DeviceInfoData>();
            DeviceInfoData did = new DeviceInfoData();
            int didSize = Marshal.SizeOf(did);
            did.Size = didSize;
            int index = 0;
            while (NativeMethods.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(handle, index, ref did))
            {
                data.Add(did);
                index += 1;
                did = new DeviceInfoData();
                did.Size = didSize;
            }
            return data.ToArray();
        }

        // Find the index of the particular DeviceInfoData for the instanceId.
        private static int GetIndexOfInstance(SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle handle, DeviceInfoData[] diData, string instanceId)
        {
            const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;
            for (int index = 0; index <= diData.Length - 1; index++)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1);
                int requiredSize = 0;
                bool result = NativeMethods.SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(handle.DangerousGetHandle(), ref diData[index], sb, sb.Capacity, out requiredSize);
                if (result == false && Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
                {
                    sb.Capacity = requiredSize;
                    result = NativeMethods.SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(handle.DangerousGetHandle(), ref diData[index], sb, sb.Capacity, out requiredSize);
                }
                if (result == false)
                    throw new Win32Exception();
                if (instanceId.Equals(sb.ToString()))
                {
                    return index;
                }
            }
            // not found
            return -1;
        }

        // enable/disable...
        private static void EnableDevice(SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle handle, DeviceInfoData diData, bool enable)
        {
            PropertyChangeParameters @params = new PropertyChangeParameters();
            // The size is just the size of the header, but we've flattened the structure.
            // The header comprises the first two fields, both integer.
            @params.Size = 8;
            @params.DiFunction = DiFunction.PropertyChange;
            @params.Scope = Scopes.Global;
            if (enable)
            {
                @params.StateChange = StateChangeAction.Enable;
            }
            else
            {
                @params.StateChange = StateChangeAction.Disable;
            }

            bool result = NativeMethods.SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(handle, ref diData, ref @params, Marshal.SizeOf(@params));
            if (result == false) throw new Win32Exception();
            result = NativeMethods.SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DiFunction.PropertyChange, handle, ref diData);
            if (result == false)
            {
                int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (err == (int)SetupApiError.NotDisableable)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Device can't be disabled (programmatically or in Device Manager).");
                else if (err >= (int)SetupApiError.NoAssociatedClass && err <= (int)SetupApiError.OnlyValidateViaAuthenticode)
                    throw new Win32Exception("SetupAPI error: " + ((SetupApiError)err).ToString());
                else
                    throw new Win32Exception();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Данный ответ взят с [en SO](http://stackoverflow.com), переведен и дополнен мной. Ссылка на источник: [Win32 API function to programmatically enable/disable device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1610140/5275890)

У каждого типа устройства есть жестко запрограммированный **GUID**, для мышки - он один, для COM-порта - другой, и так для всех устройств. Вам необходимо найти нужный **GUID** и **instancePath** и подставить в верхнем блоке кода. Данную информацию можно найти в разделе <kbd>Диспетчер устройств</kbd> в сведениях об устройстве.

Также, для корректной работы программы рекомендуется компилировать приложение в конфигурации `AnyCPU`, при этом среда разработки должна быть запущена с правами *Администратора*, иначе не будет прав доступа.

Comment: Да, спасибо за перевод и быстрый ответ. Guid {4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}. instancePath - USB\VID_191C&PID_4104\6&4D0FFC6&0&3. Выдает ошибку 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: SetupAPI error: InWow64'

Comment: @Madisson, Вам нужно посмотреть у себя на машине `instancePath` и `Guid`. В том же самом диспетчере задач можно все это посмотреть, в сведениях об устройстве. Там есть *Последний известный родительский объект* и *Родитель*, и *GUID класса*

Comment: Я использовал Последний известный родительский объект, Родитель и Путь к экземпляру устройства. Во всех случаях выскакивают ошибки. В случае с Последний известный родительский объект и Родитель выскакивает ошибка 'Additional information: Индекс находился вне границ массива.' в функции 'EnableDevice(diSetHandle, diData[index], enable)'. Но там есть массив diData в котором ровно столько элементов, сколько у меня портов. В случае с Мышкой тоже все совпало (2 элемента) но тоже выскакивает та же ошибка.

Comment: Если использовать "Путь к экземпляру устройства" то функция EnableDevice(diSetHandle, diData[index], enable) проходит нормально, и ошибка выскакивает в самом конце на функции "result = NativeMethods.SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DiFunction.PropertyChange, handle, ref diData);" Additional information: SetupAPI error: InWow64

Comment: @Madisson, вот эта ошибка говорит про то, что разрядность не совпадает: 64 и 32, скомпилируйте под другой разрядностью и запустите. Попробуйте скомпилить под  `AnyCPU`

Comment: Да, спасибо, вроде пошло но теперь оказано в доступе. Как можно подключить сюда права администратора?

Comment: @Madisson...если в среде разработки хотите, попробуйте саму IDE перезапустить с правами администратора. Либо сам исполняемый файл запустите под админом. Должно сработать

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо за помощь!