# Как отключить (или запретить любые действия) конкретную usb флешку?

Tags: c#, usb

Необходимо отключать или запрещать любые действия, на определенной флешке. Например, в компьютер вставлены 2 флешки Ф1 и Ф2. Необходимо чтобы пользователь не смог пользоваться Ф1. но при этом работал с Ф2.
Находил способ чтобы отключить всех флешек, но для конкретной, не смог получить решение.
Есть сторонний софт, которые повторяет функционал, но как он работает не смог понять.

Comment: Только ОС Windows?

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/640222/Отключение-Включение-СОМ-порта?rq=1

Comment: @Vasek, да. приоритетнее windows 10 64-bit

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, я видел этот пример (точнее, анг версию), но когда я пробовал отключить устройство, то для отключения флешки необходима была перезагрузка, а этого не должно быть.

Comment: Вероятно, дело в том, что для флешки нужно сначала выполнить безопасное извлечение устройства. Посмотрите здесь  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13839/How-to-Prepare-a-USB-Drive-for-Safe-Removal

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight в найденном мной решениях, к конкретно флешке просто отрезается доступ, а не делается извлечение

Comment: В каких найденных решениях? Я говорю о том, что если флешка вставлена и имеет активную файловую систему, ОС не дает ее отключить без безопасного извлечения (так как это может привести к потере данных).